# How to join rows of same timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two pandas dataframes with timestamp and value columns, like this:

```
                  timestamp            value1
0    2015-01-01T15:41:10.500Z    9239.337890625
1    2015-01-01T15:41:50.543Z    9539.337890625
2    2015-01-01T15:42:30.600Z    8957.0458984375
3    2015-01-01T15:43:00.606Z    8237.0458984375
```

I tried to combine them using pandas.concat

```
df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...], ignore_index = True)
df_all.sort_values(by='timestamp', inplace = True)
```

It does what I want but the result contains values like:

```
     value1      value2  timestamp
 133 9587.165039 NaN     2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z 
 0   NaN         0.14    2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

which have the same timestamp. How to join these rows so that they would become:

```
 value1      value2  timestamp
 9587.165039 0.14    2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

Any suggestion or comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: you already try `df1.merge(df2, on='timestamp')`?

Comment: @Terry , if I do like this it drops the values of d2 that are not on timestamps of d1

Comment: maybe `df1.merge(df2, on='timestamp', how='outer')` ?

Comment: @Terry, it does exactly what I wanted, Thank you very much. How do I do this for many datafiles? df1,df2,df3,df4... to combine all of them into one df ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat` will not fill the gaps. You need to do `merge` on your DataFrames. 
To merge multiple DF's, I always do:

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2, on='timestamp', how='outer')
df_new = df_new.merge(d3, on='timestamp', how='outer')
```

And go on..